# Series to_records - no object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not able to find out the reason behind this error:

```
predicted_series = pd.Series(predicted_values, index=date_list)

predicted_series = [tuple(x) for x in predicted_series.to_records(index=True)]
```

The series is created successfully, but as soon I try to execute the next line I'm facing this error.
Error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_records'

Comment: I think you are thinking of `DataFrame` instead of `Series`. `Series` does not have the `to_records` method...

Comment: Error is clear there is no method `to_records` for a `Series`, it only exists for [`DataFrames`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_records), you can convert a `Series` to a `DataFrame` by calling `to_frame()` prior to calling `to_records`